# Awaiting the generation of multiple items in a single thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, producer-consumer, async-await

*(OBS: English is not my native language and I understand that the title of this question is far from good, but I tried my best to make the question itself clear)*

Let's suppose I have a `IEnumerable<T> ts` that has MANY items and that each MoveNext() is VERY expensive - let's say `ts` was generated using a `yield return`method that makes expensive computations.

Look at this piece of code:

```
var enumerator = ts.GetEnumerator();
while (true) {
    T t = await TaskEx.Run<T>(() => enumerator.MoveNext() ? 
                                    enumerator.Current : 
                                    null);
    if (t == null) break;
    t.DoSomeLightweigthOperation(); 
}
```

It consumes the collection `ts` asynchronously, without blocking the main thread (which, in my case is a UI thread). The problem is: it spawns one thread for each item in `ts`. Is there a (simple) way to do the same thing using only ONE thread that does the entire job?

So, just to make myself clear, I want to generate these items using only one thread, but I need to get some kind of collections of `Task`s (or any other class with a `GetAwaiter`) so that I can `await` after the generation of each of these items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing solution does not spawn one thread for each item. Rather, it creates a thread pool work item that is queued to the thread pool, once for each item. It is possible (even likely) that each `MoveNext` will actually be done by the same threadpool thread.

So, I think your existing solution will work, given your constraints.

If you can change the enumerable at all, I'd consider `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`, which has a `Task<bool> MoveNext()` member. `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`/`IAsyncEnumerable<T>` are part of [Ix_Experimental-Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Ix_Experimental-Async). I also wrote a nearly-identical `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`, which is part of [Nito.AsyncEx](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/). Asynchronous enumeration is a closer match to what you're trying to do; there's a [Channel9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Rx-Update-Async-support-IAsyncEnumerable-and-more-with-Jeff-and-Wes) that describes asynchronous enumeration (though the API has changed slightly since then).

Comment: OK, thanks. My IEnumerator is written by the compiler, since im using im using a yield return method. Is there a way to make it Async?

Comment: Not easily; there's no built-in language support yet. You'd have to write your own async enumerator/enumerable implementation and post to that. It's possible that Ix_Experimental-Async may have some building blocks you can use.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is run through ts on another thread you could do something like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => 
{
   foreach(T t in ts)
   {
       t.DoSomeLightweigthOperation();
   }
});
```

Which just runs through it on a thread from the threadpool.

UPDATE: So the operation does ui work which means it needs to be queued on the ui thread. You don't say which ui framework you use but all of them have ways of doing that.

For instance if you are using wpf you can use the [dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx)

Comment: But DoSomeLightweightOperation() must be done inside the main thread. It's something that deals with the UI so it must be done on the UI thread.